# Could an implicit template deduction guide deduce a reference type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

While testing C++17 deduction guide behaviour with gcc7, I found that this example fails:

```
template<class T>
struct S{
  S(T&& v){}
};
int i=10;
auto v = S(i);
```

According to what I have read from [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), I thought `v` should be of type `S<int &>`. Nevertheless gcc7 does not compile this code complaining that a `int&` can not be bound to a `int &&` (the universal reference mechanism fails).

So my questions are:

1. Should gcc7 have deduced `v` to be of type `S<int&>`?
2. Where are described automatic deduction guide in the working draft standard?

Comment: Considering that GCC version 7 haven't been released yet, there are bound to be bugs. If this is one of them I don't know. Have you tried it with GCC 6 in C++17 mode (GCC 6 supports much of C++17)?

Comment: Deduction guide are not implemented in GCC6. I just want to know if it is cpp reference or GCC7 that is right, I cannot juge by myself because I do not find the entree in the standard...

Comment: Note that cppreference does cover this case. It's the last example on that page. Cubbi and TC don't mess around :-)

Comment: Thank you, I have modifed the text to say that this is my understanding of cpp reference that is in cause and not directly cpp reference... This look like a tautology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule in [[over.match.class.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct) is:

> A set of functions and function templates is formed comprising:
>   - For each constructor of the primary class template designated by the template-name, if the template is defined, a function template with the following properties:
>       - The template parameters are the template parameters of the class template followed by the template parameters (including default template arguments) of the constructor, if any.
>       - The types of the function parameters are those of the constructor.
>       - The return type is the class template specialization designated by the template-name and template arguments corresponding to the template parameters obtained from the class template.

Our set includes:

```
template <class T> // <-- the template parameters come from the class template
S<T>               // <-- the return type is the class template specialization   
foo(T&& );         // <-- the types of the parameters are those of the constructor
```

We perform overload resolution as usual, which involves template deduction. *But* from [[temp.deduct.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call):

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter **that does not represent a template parameter of a class template** (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])). If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Hence, this `T&&` is **not** a forwarding reference. It is an rvalue reference to `T`. So deduction against an lvalue (in our case, `S(i)`) fails. gcc is correct to reject your code here.

If you want the class template parameter to function as a forwarding reference, you will need to add a deduction guide:

```
template <class T> S(T&& ) -> S<T>;
```

Comment: Why does the deduction guide solve the issue? Doesn't `T` still represent a template parameter of a class template? Is there wording that defines what precisely `T` belongs to, here? Normally, I would take it to belong to the class template, like with a normal member function of a class template defined out of the class template body. I understand deduction guides are special beasts, so I'm asking whether there exist special rules?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In the deduction guide it's not a template parameter of a class template, it's a template parameter of a deduction guide.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I realize how that sounds.

Comment: I just read the specification and can confirm what you said. Thanks