# hana::tuple to auto && ... args

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, boost-hana

Is there a way to use something like :

```
constexpr auto foo = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<Foo1>,hana::type_c<Foo2>);
```

with something like:

```
template < typename ... Ts >
struct Final {

  constexpr Final(Ts && ... args) {}
};

hana::unpack(foo, [] (auto && ... args) { return Final(args...); });
```

Because with that code, `unpack` can't deduce lambda/function type.
Basically I want to create a type which takes a list of arguments but I have a tuple which contains the arguments.

Comment: That code isn't valid C++14 or C++17. Are you using Concepts?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't need concepts here, could you tell me why it's invalid please?

Comment: `auto` is not a valid function parameter type in C++. It's only allowed in lambda expressions.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh I remenber clang couldn't do it, but with gcc 7 I can. Not something official? The constructor was my error thought.

Comment: `auto` is a function parameter type is part of the Concepts TS (`-fconcepts`).

Comment: this is allowed in -std=gnu++11 on ubuntu, and auto as parameter should be possible in C++17 with following compiler setting on windows: /Zc:auto-
However, it still is not really working - @Kerrek SB, perhaps you could elaborate on the usage of -fconcepts

Comment: @serup in fact auto will work if your compiler started to implement Concepts TS. You don't need to specifies any std with gcc, even -fconcept isn't needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your lambda:

```
[](auto && ... args){ return Final(args...); }
//                          ~~~~~~~
```

`Final` isn't a type, it's a class template. As such, you need to explicitly provide the types. Something like:

```
[](auto&&... args){ return Final<decltype(args)...>(
    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

In C++17, with template deduction for class template parameters, the `Ts&&` does not function as a forwarding reference (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521442/2069064)), so the implicit deduction guide would not match your usage anyway as you are only providing lvalues and the guide requires revalues. But this would work:

```
[](auto... args){ return Final(std::move(args)...); }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if the constructor took the Ts by value and did the `std::move` there instead of in the lambda.

Comment: I think it should be `Final<decltype(args)&& ...>` in the second code snippet for perfect forwarding (--mind the `&&`).

Comment: @davidhigh They mean the same thing - `decltype(args)` is always a reference here.

Comment: "Here" means in the context of the OP, I guess, where a local variable `foo` is `unpack`'ed. But this doesn't hold in general, if I get it correctly, because `args` could be an rvalue ref but `decltype(args)` is deduced as lvalue ref.

Comment: @davidhigh Here meant in the place you were suggesting to change.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're actually looking for is

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct Final { ... };

constexpr auto foo = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<Foo1>,hana::type_c<Foo2>);
auto final_type = hana::unpack(foo, [](auto ...args) {
  return Final<typename decltype(args)::type...>;
});
// now, final_type is a hana::type<Final<Foo1, Foo2>>
```

You can also achieve the same thing using `hana::template_`:

```
constexpr auto foo = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<Foo1>,hana::type_c<Foo2>);
auto final_type = hana::unpack(foo, hana::template_<Final>);
```

The problem I see with Barry's answer is that you'll end up creating a `Final<decltype(hana::type_c<Foo1>), decltype(hana::type_c<Foo2>)>`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I think that you was influenced by my previous questions, because my goal is not to create a final type with a tuple of type. If you want more context, I was working with Jason Rice solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089587/change-runtime-research-for-a-compile-time-one  and I wanted to join several multi_map. Or maybe I just misunderstood your answer sorry ^^"

Comment: No worries. All I'm saying is that with Barry's solution, if you do `unpack(foo, the-lambda-he-provided)`, you end up with `Foo<type<Foo1>, type<Foo2>>`, which seems a little bit strange. In any case, I'm glad Barry's solution solves your problem.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Barry's answer doesn't address the fact that the OP `foo` is a tuple of `hana::type`.